# Prolog, writing expression with no atoms

Tags: prolog, logic

New to Prolog and I want to be able to answer this question while getting a good understanding of whats going on

> Write a predicate no_atoms/1 which succeeds iff its argument is an expression without
> any atoms. For example, no_atoms(5-(3+x)) should fail, no_atoms((12+8)-7)
> should succeed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to test that the expression is not an atom. Then, you check with compound/1 if you need to enumerate the arguments with arg/3 or succeed.

```
no_atoms(Expr) :-
    \+ atom(Expr),
    (   compound(Expr)
    ->  \+ ( arg(_, Expr, A), \+ no_atoms(A) )
    ;   true
    ).
```