# How to solve this Prolog question by filtering out the atoms?

Tags: prolog

so I am given the expression with the description

> We can, in fact, specify in Prolog what an expression is:

> is_expression(X):- var(X), !, fail.

> is_expression(X):- atom(X); number(X).

> is_expression(X+Y):- is_expression(X), is_expression(Y).

> is_expression(X-Y):- is_expression(X), is_expression(Y).

And the question asks

Write a predicate no_atoms/1 which succeeds if its argument is an expression without
any atoms. For example, no_atoms(5-(3+x)) should fail, no_atoms((12+8)-7)
should succeed.

I am new to Prolog and don't really know where to start with this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757380/prolog-writing-expression-with-no-atoms

Comment: Thanks for showing me, does the answer not change depending on the expression?